# Why isn't the array I return in my __construct class available in the following function?

Tags: php, function, class

I've written a class which in the construct accesses the db and gets a list of names. These names go into an associative array e.g. ('name' => 'id').

i.e. the point is to pass in the name to get back an ID:

```
$id = names::nameToId('some name');
print $id;
// prints int
```

The problem is when I try and return the array from the construct I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: nameArray in (etc)

Here is the code so far:

```
class nameToId {
    public $nameArray;
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli) {
        ...
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $nameArray[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
        }

        return $nameArray;
    }

    static public function nameToId($name) {
        $nameId = $nameArray[$name];
        return $nameId;
    }
}

$namesToId = new nameToId($mysqli);
$nameId = $namesToId::nameToId('some name');
echo $nameId;
```

Why doesn't $nameArray get passed to nameToId()? I'm new to classes, and I thought by declaring $nameArray as public when I first create the class that it would make it available. I have also tried to make it global even though I know that is not good form but even still it didn't work.

Comment: Because calling a class constructor using `new` ___always___ returns the __instance of the class__, irrespective of any code in that constructor that uses a `return` statement, so your returned value is ignored - [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)

Comment: You should not return the array, but assign it to $this -> nameArray;

Comment: if you want to use static function , then you need to use static attribute . look , you didn't set `$nameArray;` of your class. change `return $nameArray` into this `$this->nameArray=$nameArray;`

Comment: I had tried to set ```$this->nameArray = $nameArray``` in the construct already, but end up with "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context"

Comment: Downvoting without giving a reason doesn't do much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you cannot `return` anything from a constructor. Any `return` value is being ignored and just goes into the aether. `$nameArray` is a local variable and is not shared in any other scope, i.e. you can't access it in `nameToId`. Further, since `nameToId` is `static`, it won't have access to data from any non-static methods like `__construct` to begin with.

You probably want something like this:

```
class nameToId {

    public $nameArray;
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli) {
        ...
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $this->nameArray[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
        }
    }

    public function nameToId($name) {
        return $this->nameArray[$name];
    }
}


$namesToId = new nameToId($mysqli);
echo $namesToId->nameToId('some name');
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explaining this. And it works.

Answer (score -1):

Fix your code:

```
class nameToId {
    public static $nameArray;
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqli) {

        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM teams';
        $res = mysqli_query($this->mysqli,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            self::$nameArray[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
        }
    }

    static public function nameToId($name) {
        $nameId = self::$nameArray[$name];
        return $nameId;
    }
}

$namesToId = new nameToId($mysqli);
$nameId = $namesToId::nameToId('some name');
echo $nameId;
```